# Can't change brightness when installing

Tags: boot, brightness

I'm kind of newbie in ubuntu. After several hours of research and trail, I finally managed to boot into Ubuntu installation screen via USB. However, my screen brightness is really really dim, I can barley see what's on the screen. Because I haven't officially install the ubuntu, I cannot use terminal to adjust it. So anyone offer some suggestions? Thanks a lot, I don't want to stop at here.

Comment: can you share some screen shots?

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I can't. It is too dark to basically read anything. But I'm sure it is on the installation steps. Right, also, the [Fn] key doesn't work.